# Server 2012 SMTP Server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, smtp

I've stood up two SMTP servers using windows server 2012 r2, they send out email just fine but when an email does fail and we get a bounce back. Is that stored in a file somewhere so that I can use Powershell to gather all those failed emails into one report?

I want to have one list instead of everytime we have a bounce back it sends a single email.

Answer (score 0):

NDR's are sent to the original sender of the email. Emails that can't be delivered will be moved to the Badmail folder.

You can designate the email address that NDR's are sent to if you want them sent to a specific email address.

Comment: I'm finding that not all bad emails are going into the bad email folder. I'm already forwarding the bad emails to a shared email address. When I received the bad email I checked the bad email folder and nothing was in there for that bad email. Does it remove that log file once it sends the failure to the shared mailbox?